# Create Two Ellipse/Arcs from Straight Line Segments

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line, ellipse

I have thousands of straight line segments (all separate features). I need to convert each straight line segment into two arcs, with the arcs opposite of each other. For example, I used the XY to Line tool and selected Great Circle line type to create the arcs. That gives me one arc, but I need an arc opposite of that (like a reverse great circle arc). It does not necessarily have to be a great circle arc, just an arc of some sort. I have also tried to use the table to ellipse tool and it does not work as I anticipated.

The picture below explains what I am trying to do. The red line is the straight line which I already have. The blue lines are what I am needing. I can get the top blue line by selecting Great Circle in the XY to Line tool, but I somehow need to create another arc in the opposite direction, which is what the bottom line represents.

I am using ArcGIS for Desktop 10.2.2 Advanced and have full access to any tools/features.

[image: Arc]

Comment: Please [edit] your Question and include your ArcGIS Desktop version, and a picture of what it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: ArcMap has a "Mirror Features" tool. This will create a mirror image copy of a feature, across a line. It is available in the Customize menu.

Comment: I tried using that tool. That works when doing it manually, but I have thousands of lines to create arcs from. I need an automated way of using that tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your table of content put empty polyline feature class on the very top.
Place your layer with curves underneath and run script.

Original:

[image]

Mirror:

[image]

Script:

```
import arcpy, traceback, os, sys, time

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
mirror=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[0]
original=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[1]

try:
    def showPyMessage():
        arcpy.AddMessage(str(time.ctime()) + " - " + message)

    curT=arcpy.da.InsertCursor(mirror,"Shape@")
    g=arcpy.Geometry()
    geomList=arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(original, g)
    n=len(geomList)
    for shp in geomList:
        part=[p for p in shp.getPart(0)]
        straight=arcpy.Polyline(arcpy.Array([part[0],part[-1]]))
        mirList=arcpy.Array()
        for p in part:
            dL=straight.measureOnLine(p)
            theP=straight.positionAlongLine(dL).firstPoint
            pM=arcpy.Point(2*theP.X-p.X,2*theP.Y-p.Y)
            mirList.add(pM)
        mirLine=arcpy.Polyline(mirList)
        curT.insertRow((mirLine,))
    del mxd
except:
    message = "\n*** PYTHON ERRORS *** "; showPyMessage()
    message = "Python Traceback Info: " + traceback.format_tb(sys.exc_info()[2])[0]; showPyMessage()
    message = "Python Error Info: " +  str(sys.exc_type)+ ": " + str(sys.exc_value) + "\n"; showPyMessage()
```

Comment: Thank you for the script. I tried using it, and for some reason it creates straight lines connecting the endpoints of the curves, not the mirror of the original curve. I will try to manipulate your script and see if I can get it to mirror the curves. In case this makes a difference, every curve is an individual curve, not curves that are connected to each other.

Comment: I tested it on projected feature class, shapefile

Comment: It won't work on true curves

Comment: It's possible it did not work because my data was not projected. Regardless, I tried it again on a projected shapefile and it works. Thank you.